# Spring Loading issue - context Config Location

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web.xml

/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>Sample</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-mail.xml
            </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>CustomCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>edu.am.bigdata.web.filter.CustomCacheFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CustomCacheFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>



  <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.am.bigdata.web"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>file:/usr/local/application.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
  <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
        </property>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}">
        </property>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>UserDetails.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>Role.hbm.xml</value>

        </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!--  property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property-->
    </bean> 

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
         <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"/>
         <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="edu.am.bigdata.web" />

</beans:beans>
```

I have problem in loading my project when I run on Server. I get an error like

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: class edu.am.bigdata.web.domain.User not found while looking for property: id
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: class edu.am.bigdata.web.domain.User not found while looking for property: id
```

This was previously working for me, When i put my code in other system, this is not working. I use tomcat7.0 Server.

Can anyone Solve my issue?
Thanks--

Comment: So, does your edu.am.bigdata.web.domain.User have a property called id with a public setter and getter?

Comment: Yes Its having No problem in that

Comment: Hmm strange, I would make sure that there is not some old code lying around or something - sorry

Comment: Is the User class in the package edu.am.bigdata.web.domain? Is this class in WEB-INF/classes?

Comment: Its in the package  edu.am.bigdata.web.domain only @JB nizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer may be strange, But it worked out for me. I found that some problem with the Spring  and hibernate, so I refreshed the whole project, Imported the same project in a new workspace and run it. The problem is fixed. I really don't know the reasons behind this has been fixed.

--Thank you